# Writing a program using vtkLinearExtrusionFilter to form a bar chart which has to pull data from a .CSV file and display it

Tags: c++, csv, vtk

I have to write a VTK based program using vtkLinearExtrusionFilter to "display" data which are pulled from a .CSV file to make it as a bar chart. Now, I've been hammering my head for few days now(!) and still can't get it to work.....

I've tried to make some alterations to examples I found here:

```
vtkLinearExtrusionFilter example: http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/PolyData/LinearExtrusion
```

This is the text of the assignment:

```
It is necessary to create a, so-called, bar chart using vtkLinearExtrusionFilter object that will run
selected data consumption per capita. 
Data are stored on:
```

http://www.infochimps.com/datasets/per-capita-consumption-of-major-food-commodities-1980-to-2005

```
Base vtkLinearExtrusionFilter filters will be a square of arbitrary dimensions.
```

Now, here's what I cooked up:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <ctype.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <vector>

#include "vtkPolyDataMapper.h" 
#include "vtkActor.h" 
#include "vtkRenderer.h" 
#include "vtkRenderWindow.h" 
#include "vtkRenderWindowInteractor.h" 
#include "vtkLinearExtrusionFilter.h" 
#include "vtkProperty.h" 
#include "vtkCamera.h"
#include <vtkDelimitedTextReader.h>
#include <vtkSmartPointer.h>
#include <vtkTable.h>
#include <vtkPolyData.h>
#include <vtkPoints.h>
#include <vtkPolygon.h>
#include <vtkCellArray.h>


#define VTK_CREATE(type, name) \
vtkSmartPointer<type> name = vtkSmartPointer<type>::New()



int main( int argc, char *argv[] )  
{ 
int row=0, col=0;

std::string inputFilename;// = "build/ConsumptionOfMajorFood.csv";

if ( argc == 2)
{
    inputFilename = argv[1];
}
else
{
    inputFilename = "statab2008_0205_PerCapitaConsumptionOfMajorFoodComm_0_Data.csv";
}

//reading from file - creating the reader
VTK_CREATE(vtkDelimitedTextReader, reader);
reader->SetFileName(inputFilename.c_str());
reader->DetectNumericColumnsOn();
reader->SetFieldDelimiterCharacters(",");//comma is the separator
reader->Update();

vtkTable* table = reader->GetOutput();//table with data


//kreating and setting renderer
vtkRenderer *ren = vtkRenderer::New(); 
vtkRenderWindow *renWin = vtkRenderWindow::New(); 
renWin->AddRenderer(ren); 
//interaction
vtkRenderWindowInteractor *iren = vtkRenderWindowInteractor::New(); 
iren->SetRenderWindow(renWin); 

//structures for keeping pointers on needed elements
std::vector<vtkLinearExtrusionFilter*> vecFilters;
std::vector<vtkPolyData*> vecRects;
std::vector<vtkPoints*> vecPoints;
std::vector<vtkCellArray*> vecCells;
std::vector<vtkPolyDataMapper*> mappers;
std::vector<vtkActor*> actors;

//rectangle dimensions 
int rowOffset=5;
int colOffset=5;
int rectSize = 3;

//reading from 15th to 80th row
for (vtkIdType row = 15; row < 80; row++)
{
    //columns with data in file
    for (vtkIdType col = 2; col < 10; col++)
    {
        long value = table->GetValue(row,col).ToLong();//values from file

        if (value<0)
          value=0;

        //extrude filter
        vtkLinearExtrusionFilter *extrudeFilter = vtkLinearExtrusionFilter::New(); 
        vecFilters.push_back(extrudeFilter);

        //points for square base
        vtkPoints *points = vtkPoints::New(); 
        points->InsertNextPoint(0, 0, 0); 
        points->InsertNextPoint(rectSize, 0, 0); 
        points->InsertNextPoint(rectSize,rectSize, 0); 
        points->InsertNextPoint(0, rectSize, 0);//create 4 points 

        vecPoints.push_back(points);

        //creating polygons with points
        vtkPolygon *polygon = vtkPolygon::New(); 
        polygon->GetPointIds()->SetNumberOfIds(4); 
        polygon->GetPointIds()->SetId(0, 0); 
        polygon->GetPointIds()->SetId(1, 1); 
        polygon->GetPointIds()->SetId(2, 2); 
        polygon->GetPointIds()->SetId(3, 3);// 

        vtkCellArray *cells = vtkCellArray::New(); 
        cells->InsertNextCell(polygon); 

        vecCells.push_back(cells);


        vtkPolyData *polyData = vtkPolyData::New(); 
        polyData->SetPoints(points); 
        polyData->SetPolys(cells); 

        vecRects.push_back(polyData);

        //setting extrude
        extrudeFilter->SetInput(polyData); //extruding base
        extrudeFilter->SetExtrusionType(VTK_VECTOR_EXTRUSION); 
        extrudeFilter->SetVector(0,0,1.0); //direction
        extrudeFilter->SetScaleFactor((float)value / 10); //square size

        //creating datamappera and actora
        vtkPolyDataMapper* mapper = vtkPolyDataMapper::New(); 
        mappers.push_back(mapper);
        mapper->SetInput(extrudeFilter->GetOutput()); 
        mapper->ScalarVisibilityOff(); 
        vtkActor* actor = vtkActor::New();
        actors.push_back(actor);
        actor->SetMapper(mapper); 
        actor->GetProperty()->SetColor(0.2000, 0.6300, 0.7900); 

        if ( value == 0 ) 
            actor->VisibilityOff(); 

        actor->SetPosition(row * rowOffset, col*colOffset, 0.0); 

        //adding actor to rendering engine
        ren->AddActor(actor); 
    }
}

//initializing view window
renWin->SetSize(800, 600); 
renWin->Render(); 


// staring interaction with the view
iren->Start(); 

// purging the taken memory
ren->Delete(); 
renWin->Delete(); 
iren->Delete(); 

for (int i=0; i < vecRects.size(); i++)
{
    vecFilters[i]->Delete(); 
    vecCells[i]->Delete(); 
    vecRects[i]->Delete(); 
    vecPoints[i]->Delete(); 
    mappers[i]->Delete(); 
    actors[i]->Delete(); 
}

exit( 0 ); 

return 0;
}
```

Here's the CMakeLists:

```
PROJECT (Work2)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
IF(NOT VTK_BINARY_DIR)
FIND_PACKAGE(VTK REQUIRED)
IF(NOT VTK_USE_RENDERING)
  MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "Example ${PROJECT_NAME} requires VTK_USE_RENDERING.")
ENDIF(NOT VTK_USE_RENDERING)
INCLUDE(${VTK_USE_FILE})
ENDIF(NOT VTK_BINARY_DIR)
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})

ADD_EXECUTABLE(Work2 Work2.cpp)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(Work2 vtkRendering vtkInfovis)
```

Now, the CMake builds it without a hitch and it creates a Visualisation Toolkit window but it's blank and there's nothing showing.
As if there was no data stored in the file but there are 11 columns and 81 rows total of data.

Now, can somebody with more experience than me show me, **WITH** appropriate solution code, how to rectify this?

P.S. I'll be waiting patiently, so ask me for more info if you need it.

Comment: Anything? Please? No one has any idea how to solve this?